# Find out the previous year date from current date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to find out the previous year date from current date and then set as minDate in jQuery UIdatepicker in javascript

My date formaqt is `dd-mm-yy`

Ie

- current date is `25-07-2012`
- I need to get `25-07-2011`

Comment: And what if it is a leap year and you are on the leap day?

Answer (score 63):

You need to use [`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear)

and then generate new Date

```
var d = new Date(2012, 7, 25);
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() - 1);
```

Comment: For more information refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/

Comment: jan=0 so jul=6 for some absurd reason with js months

Answer (score 21):

Try this

```
var d = new Date();
var pastYear = d.getFullYear() - 1;
d.setFullYear(pastYear);
console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 13):

this solution will help.

```
new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 1));
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this :

```
 var date = new Date();
 var intYear = date.getFullYear() - 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Datepicker allows you to put a number as the `minDate` option, and it uses that as an offset from the current date. So you can write:

```
minDate: -365
```

to specify 1 year ago. This doesn't take leap years into account, though.

Answer (score 2):

For strings:

```
curdate.substr(0, 6)+(curdate.substr(6)-1);
```

If you'd use a [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/), you could easily subtract a year with the `set[Full]Year` method.

Answer (score 1):

you can define a new date or an existing date as d variable

```
var d = new Date();
```

then you can put date, month and year to the new date string using `${variableName}`,
Also you must add 1 to d.getMonth() and substract 1 from d.getFullYear()

```
var previousYearDate = `${d.getDate()}-${d.getMonth() + 1}-${d.getFullYear() - 1}`;
```

Comment: It's better to add some details around your answer.

Comment: Yeah... I will do it :)

Comment: ela machan this is nice

Answer (score 0):

```
var today = new Date();
var curyear = today.getFullYear();
var curyearMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
var curyearDay = today.getDate();
var lastYear = curyear - 1;
if ((curyearMonth == 2) && (curyearDay == 29)) {
    curyearDay = 28;
}

var lastYearDisplay = ("0000" + lastYear.toString()).slice(-4) + "-" + ("00" + curyearMonth.toString()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("00" + curyearDay.toString()).slice(-2);
alert("LastWeekDate : " + lastYearDisplay);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this very useful:

```
new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 1)).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

Answer (score -1):

To avoid the Date object (if that is what OP wishes):

```
var currDate = '25-07-2012';
var dateParts = currDate.split('-');
dateParts[2] = parseInt(dateParts[2], 10) - 1;
alert(dateParts.join('-'));​
```

Comment: Will not properly work with the leap year and 29th of Feb

Answer (score -1):

```
var date = CALC.today(); //(function in my dev-enviro - gives today's date)
var year = formatDate(date, 'yyyy'); //year is 2016
year = parseInt(year);               //make sure '2016' becomes an integer
year = year -1;                      // var year is now: 2015.

//its been a while, but that's what I did from memory.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  function getTodayDate() {
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is not 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if (dd < 10) { dd = '0' + dd }
        if (mm < 10) { mm = '0' + mm }
        today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
        return today;
    };
    function getYearAgo(){
    var lastYear = new Date();
    var dd = lastYear.getDate();
    var mm = lastYear.getMonth() + 1; //January is not 0!
    var yyyy = lastYear.getFullYear(getTodayDate) - 1;
    if (dd < 10) { dd = '0' + dd }
    if (mm < 10) { mm = '0' + mm }
    lastYear = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;     
    return lastYear;
    }
```