# Efficiently create Javascript Date from Today -1 Years (time) in Unix time

Tags: javascript

I currently am using this to create a Unix time stamp for time (now) -1 year's time.

Can someone please share a better and more efficient way to do this?

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
var lastYear = parseInt(currentYear) - 1;
var lastYearDateObj = new Date(lastYear, currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate(), currentDate.getHours(), currentDate.getMinutes());
var lastYearTime = lastYearDateObj.getTime() / 1000;
```

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [find out the previous year date from current date in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649672/find-out-the-previous-year-date-from-current-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what your division by 1000 is about.  You can add it to the end if you like:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - 1);
// date.getTime() / 1000 // if you want.
```

Comment: `getTime` returns milliseconds, so dividing by 1000 gives seconds (unix time in seconds).

Comment: I've always used timestamps in milliseconds (or microseconds in some systems), not just seconds.    That's why I didn't understand.  Is there some Unix timestamp in seconds?

Comment: *"Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970,[note 1] not counting leap seconds."* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Thanks.  Just looking at that.  Strange that I've always used milli- or micro-second timestamps from other systems.