# filter array of timestamps by 'last week', 'last month' and 'last year'

Tags: javascript, arrays, timestamp

I have an array of timestamps and values where I'm converting each timestamp to a date. I have some function where it shows the date from oldest to newest. I want to calculate `last week`, `last month` and `last year` based on today's date.

```js
const myData = [
  {timestamp: 1382086394000, value: 200},
  {timestamp: 1382086394001, value: 200},
  {timestamp: 1232131231232, value: 300},
  {timestamp: 2131231241212, value: 400},
  {timestamp: 1234124124112, value: 285},
  {timestamp: 1251251251251, value: 123},
  {timestamp: 1241241241241, value: 512},
  {timestamp: 1241241241241, value: 124},
  {timestamp: 2312312123121, value: 600},
];
```

This is the array looks like, keep in mind that I already have converted timestamp to an acutal date.

Comment: Imagine doing this on 2020-02-12 (a friday). What is your definition of "last week"? The last seven full days (ie 2020-02-05 to 2020-02-11)? Last seven days including today (2020-02-06 to 2020-02-12)? The the last full week from sunday (monday) to saturday (sunday), ie 2020-01-31 to 2020-02-06 (2020-02-01 to 2020-02-07)?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649672/find-out-the-previous-year-date-from-current-date-in-javascript/11649716

Comment: @derpirscher If today we assume it's a friday, the last week would be the last seven days from friday including friday.

Comment: And how about last month? Is it the last 30/31 days or, assuming today, jan 1st to jan 31st? And last year? The last 365 days, or jan 1st to dec 31st?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Moment.js manipulating functions](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/) like add or subtract for this.

```
let timestamp = 1382086394000; 
console.log(moment(timestamp )) // Moment<2013-10-18T08:53:14+00:00>

// this is date after a week from the given timestamp
console.log(moment(timestamp ).add(1, 'w')) // Moment<2013-10-25T08:53:14+00:00>
```

You can do this for getting the last week, month and year by subtracting accordingly. Moment.js takes care of all the edge cases you might encounter.

Comment: Please keep in mind, that the mainainters of momentsjs announced that it is now deprected ... So it's not recommended when starting new projects ...

Comment: I installed momentjs and it is not giving me a date when I do `moment(timestamp)`

Comment: @5865 can you update your question with the new code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily calculate the last year (assuming full year Jan 1st to Dec 31st 2020 if current year is 2021) and last month (assuming full month Jan 1st to Jan 31st if current date is Feb) and last week (as for your comment the last 7 days, including today) as follows.

I use an semi-open interval (ie the end of the period is not included) so you don't have to create timestamps like 23:59:59.999. Thus you have to compare with `<` for the end.

Using `getMonth()-1` or `getDate()-6` will make use of the internal calcuations in the constructor of the date object. So for instance `new Date(2021, 0, -3)` will create the 28th of December 2020

```js
let today = new Date();
console.log(today.toLocaleString());

let lastYearStart = new Date(today.getFullYear()-1, 0, 1);
let lastYearEnd = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 0, 1);

console.log(lastYearStart.toLocaleString());
console.log(lastYearEnd.toLocaleString());


let lastMonthEnd = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1);
let lastMonthStart = new Date(lastMonthEnd.getFullYear(), lastMonthEnd.getMonth()-1, 1);

console.log(lastMonthStart.toLocaleString());
console.log(lastMonthEnd.toLocaleString());

let lastWeekStart = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()-6);
let lastWeekEnd = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()+1);

console.log(lastWeekStart.toLocaleString());
console.log(lastWeekEnd.toLocaleString());

const mydata = [
  {timestamp: 1382086394000, value: 200},
  {timestamp: 1382086394001, value: 200},
  {timestamp: 1232131231232, value: 300},
  {timestamp: 2131231241212, value: 400},
  {timestamp: 1234124124112, value: 285},
  {timestamp: 1251251251251, value: 123},
  {timestamp: 1241241241241, value: 512},
  {timestamp: 1241241241241, value: 124},
  {timestamp: 2312312123121, value: 600},
];

for (let d of mydata) {
  if (d.timestamp >= lastWeekStart.getTime() && d.timestamp < lastWeekEnd.getTime())
    console.log("last week");
  else if (d.timestamp >= lastMonthStart.getTime() && d.timestamp < lastMonthEnd.getTime())
    console.log("last month");
  else if (d.timestamp >= lastYearStart.getTime() && d.timestamp < lastYearEnd.getTime())
    console.log("last year");
}
```

Of course, a certain timestamp may (depending on the current date) be all three categories, last week, last month, last year. You may need to adapt classification accordingly (ie use only `if` instead of `else if`) if it should be able to classified one timestamp in more than one category

Comment: Nice one, but when I do by last week, last month it shows data from the highest to the lowest. For example it shows first January 5 then January 1, which is supposed to be the other way around.

Comment: It traverses the array in the original order. If you want them sorted, you'll need to sort either the original data or split them into various categories and then sort within categories.

Comment: what If i wanted to filter 3 months and 6 months ago, what code do I use?

Comment: @5865 the same as with lastmonth, but instead of `getMonth()-1` use `getMonth()-3` or `getMonth()-6` (or whatever number of month you want) for start